# Customized Spotify Play Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, spotify

I know that the Spotify Play Button doesn't support autoplay.
Has anyone got an idea if there's any way to work around this?

Or even better - a customized button to play/pause Spotify songs.

Comment: Well, I haven't any documentation on this whatsoever so I thought there might someone who knows if this is even possible. I don't need a finished code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Spotify Connect Web API. You can see the documentation here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-connect-endpoint-reference/

You can bind the onclick event of your custom button to call the `play` or `pause` endpoints.